# Can't send integer to HashSet constructor

Tags: java, constructor, hashset

I tried to initialize HashSet with int but it didn't work.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>(123456);
    a.add(55);
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Output:
[55]

Why it's happening and how can I send a single int to HashSet constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `new HashSet<Integer>(123456)` is supposed to do?  Did you read the Javadoc?

Comment: add 123456 as a first element...?

Comment: Read the Javadoc please.

Comment: @J.Doe Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Integer` you pass to the `HashSet` constructor represents the initial capacity of the `Set`. It doesn't add that value to the `Set`.

If you want to construct a `Set` with a single element, you can use (in Java 9):

```
Set<Integer> a = Set.of(123456);
```

Note that this `Set` will be immutable.

If you want a mutable `Set`, you can pass the immutable `Set` to its constructor:

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>(Set.of(123456));
```

Or, in Java 7:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(123456));
```

Comment: What can I do in Java 7?

Comment: @J.Doe You can use `Arrays.asList` to create a `List` and pass that `List` to the `HashSet` constructor.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The [`HashSet(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-int-) constructor allows you specify its **initial capacity**.

If you want to initialize its elements, you'll need to use the [`HashSet(Colletion)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-java.util.Collection-) constructor. E.g.:

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(123456));
```

Comment: Is that the only way to pass single element to HashSet constructor..?

Comment: @J.Doe You can use other collections, such as `Collections.singletonList`, `Arrays.asList` or even Java 9's `Set.of`, but you'll have to use a collection of some sort.